# for loop misery

Tags: python, arrays

I'm trying to loop through an array, compute some values and store them in another array (`output`). However, what I tried (see bellow) always prints the last value in the `inarray` and the last computed `sum` (not the max value, as intended) and the `output` array also only contains the last value. I figured the `output.append(sum)` should append the `sum` value each time throughout the loop, but it doesn't. If I print the sum values directly though, it shows on the console. What am I doing wrong?

```
def discountCombinations(inarray):
    for i in range(len(inarray)):
        max = 0
        maxi = 0
        output = list()
        ...
        #do stuff
        ...
        sum = new_y.sum()
        output.append(sum)
        print sum
        if sum > max:
            max = copy.copy(sum)
            maxi = copy.copy(i)
    print (max,": ", inarray[maxi])
    print output
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're resetting max, maxi, and output for every input item you process. You should only do this once, before processing any input items, for example:

```
max = 0
maxi = 0
output = list()

for i in range(len(inarray)):
    ...
    #do stuff
    ...
```

Answer (score 5):

`output  = list()` is defined in the for loop, so the result of the previous append is destroyed at the next iteration of the loop. Your `max` and `maxi` values are equally defined in the loop, and the same thing follows.

Answer (score 1):

In each iteration you are re-initializing the variable "output" as an empty list in this line: "output = list()". You just need to move this line before "for" loop.